# Identify this series about mental psi powers

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I remember a series when I was younger, where the humans were stranded on a planet where they had been pursued by aliens. They had bonded with mind alien:power, the norm was 1-2max, and the protagonist ended up bonding with a lot. I just can’t seem to find enough detail to search for it via Google.

Comment: Was this a book or television series? When exactly did you read/watch this? Why were the aliens pursuing the humans? What did the aliens look like?

Comment: I voted to reopen since there is an answer that may very well be correct.

Answer (score 5):

**CYCLE OF FIRE**

I believe this is Janny Wurtz' early *[The Cycle of Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janny_Wurts#The_Cycle_of_Fire_Trilogy)* trilogy: *Stormwarden* (1984), *Keeper of the Keys* (1988), *Shadowfane* (1988), with a collected edition from 1999.

[image]

At first, it reads like fantasy, but it turns out (in the second book, I believe) to be science fiction. The young, male protagonist, Jaric, becomes a wizard as he manages to absorb an elemental demon inside himself. He later binds a second demon, a rare feat, since the demons will team up to overpower the wizard. It is revealed at one point that the demons are bodiless space aliens and enemies of mankind (there's a robot in a buried spaceship who tells this to the female protagonist, Taen). At the end, Jaric accidently absorbs a dozen or so 'demons', who start fighting each other as well as himself. Somehow, he manages to persuade them that their only chance of survival is to ally with himself and each other. He thus becomes the first 'wizard' to bind many 'demons'. This heralds a new age of powerful 'wizards' hosting many 'demons', who stop warring on mankind. (I may misremember some details, but this is the gist of it).

Comment: There are actually several kinds of demons/aliens.  One of the types of demons exist as crystals, which can bond with a human and give them psychic powers.  Usually 1, 2 or (with great difficulty and insanity) 3.  The hero is forced to bond with many accidentally and becomes more powerful than any before him.  And the humans were on the planet for centuries after their starship crashed while being pursued by the aliens, who they were at war with.  The ship had been sent out to find a weapon for the humans to fight back against the demons/aliens' physical and psychic powers.